# I am writing a code to check if number is a palindrome or not. But when i check the output for 2 numbers, its coming different

Tags: javascript, encoding, palindrome

```js
function allPalindromicPerms(num) {
  
  // find reverse of a number and then
  // comapre the reversed number with the main number
  
  var finalNum = 0;
  var originalNum = num;
  let remainder = 0;
  while (num) {
    remainder = num % 10;
    console.log('remainder' + remainder);
    num = num - remainder;
    num = num / 10;
    finalNum = finalNum * 10 + remainder;
    console.log(finalNum);
  }
  if (finalNum == originalNum) {
    console.log("is palindrome");
  } else {
    console.log("not a palindrome");
  }
}

allPalindromicPerms(23456788888765432) // with the the output is coming fine. 

allPalindromicPerms(234567888888765432) // but this is not giving me right output.
```

Could you help me what is wrong?

Comment: This is easier using a string

Answer (score 2):

This is because both those numbers are greater than the [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

```js
const a = 23456788888765432;
const b = 234567888888765432;

console.log('                 ↓                  ↓\n', a, b)
console.log(a > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, b > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
```

To work with numbers this big, it's better to stick to strings or use the [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). Being a palindrome is a lexical property anyway.

Please see the below example solution:

```js
const isPalindrome = n => `${n}`.split('').reverse().join('') === n + '';

console.log(
  isPalindrome(23456788888765432n),
  isPalindrome(234567888888765432n),
  isPalindrome('23456788888765432'),
  isPalindrome('234567888888765432')
);
```

Comment: a superb answer!

Answer (score 0):

That's because this `234567888888765432` is bigger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` which is `9007199254740991`

You can't expect any math operators to work with numbers bigger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

You could use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) or just a string